# Making Changes to List Causes DataGridView to show blank

Tags: c#, list, winforms, datagridview

I have a project where a user can add new products or modify existing ones. Products can have parts associated with them. I created a list in the class where my product constructor lives to hold parts for each product.

I'm trying to figure out how to set up that if a user makes changes to the parts that are associated with a product but hits the cancel button then the list reverts to the original list. If they hit the save button after making edits to the products parts list then the updated list is saved and when they open the product again then the updated list displays.

All the code in the file I have is quite a bit but the parts I thought would be most helpful for what I have are...

Filling in the product text boxes with the information on the product. Populating the datagridview CurrentPartsDataGrid with the tempParts list that is a copy of the product.Parts list. Or creating a new empty list if it's a new product that is created.

```
 if (product != null)
 {
    ProductIdText.Text = product.ID.ToString();
    ProductNameText.Text = product.Name.ToString();
    InvText.Text = product.QOH.ToString();
    PriceText.Text = product.Price.ToString();
    InvMinText.Text = product.Min.ToString();
    InvMaxText.Text = product.Max.ToString();

    tempParts = new BindingList<Part>(product.Parts);
  }
  else
  {
    product = new Product();
    tempParts = new BindingList<Part>();
  }
  CurrentPartsDataGrid.DataSource = tempParts;
```

In the save/cancel button click event methods I have tried doing a for loop or for each loop. I clear the list and then try to repopulate.

Code in save

```
    product.Parts.Clear();
    foreach (Part part in tempParts)
    { 
       product.Parts.Add(part);
    }
```

Code in Cancel

```
    tempParts.Clear();

    foreach (Part part in product.Parts)
    {
       tempParts.Add(part);
    }
```

If there is anything else that would be helpful, let me know. I'm new to posting here so don't want to overload the post but also don't want to not provide enough.

Any help on how to fix this would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: This may or may not work for BindingList<> as a DataSource.  The following works for me using a BindingSource.DataSource = DataTable.DefaultView where DataGridView.DataSource = BindingSource.  If you make edits to a DataGridView, commit them with `DataGridView.EndEdit();` followed by a `BindingSource.EndEdit();` else if you are making changes to Controls using the same BindingSource, then do the `BindingSource.EndEdit();` Before the `DataGridView.EndEdit();`  My point is, if you do not *commit* your changes with an *EndEdit();* in appropriate sequence, the changes could blank out.

Comment: Try putting a `CurrentPartsDataGrid.EndEdit();` in your `Save();` procedure.

Comment: That didn't seem to do the trick. Something about creating a new product as well is not working as expected which I assume is related to all this trouble as well. Maybe because of my `tempParts = new BindingList<Part> (product.Part);`

Seems like whatever I end up doing to `tempParts` also happens to `product.Parts` which I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up not needing to do any of the EndEdit() stuff.

In my `(if product != null)`

I added

```
 tempList = new BindingList<Part>();
                for (int i = 0; i < product.Parts.Count; i++)
                {
                    tempList.Add(product.Parts[i]);
                }
```

This created a new templist that when the user selected cancel I set `product.Parts = tempList` which resolved the issue.